# Gridster widget sticks to mouse when scrollbar inside widget is clicked in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, gridster

I have some [gridster](http://gridster.net/) widgets on my page. 
Within my widgets I have a div that has an `overflow-y` set to `true`.

In IE, if I click the scrollbar inside the widget, the widget will stick to my mouse and I have to right click to drop it.

This is not an issue in Google Chrome.

```
<li class="widget">
    <div style="overflow-y:true; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
       ... some stuff
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a work around you can attach event to to scroller by using element.attachBrowserEvent for the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events .

Than disable / enable the drag options  ==>  $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster).disable / enable .

Tried it and it works fine..

Regards,
Arie